# GitHub Actions overrides provisioner user in molecule test

Tags: ansible, github-actions, molecule

I have a project that utilizes Molecule for testing, and I've configured my `molecule.yml` file to use an unprivileged user (already created on the image pushed to a registry) named `molecule` during provisioning:

```yaml
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  connection_options:
    ansible_ssh_user: molecule
```

I added a small playbook that reproduces the error on Github Actions https://github.com/staticdev/nix-playbook/tree/feature/enable-flakes, it basically install nix package manager with [Ableton/nix role].

When I run molecule test locally, everything works as expected and the provisioning process executes with the `molecule` user. However, when I push my code to GitHub and trigger the same command in a GitHub Actions workflow, it runs the test with a user named `runner`, causing issues in my tests.

Why does this override occur specifically in the GA environment and is there a way to bypass or override this behavior? I tried to find something in GA documentation and searching on internet but found nothing relevant.

---

UPDATE: the initial config I was previously trying an is old way to configure it (below) but new way it the one I am trying now (above). They both work locally but not on GitHub Actions.

```yaml
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  config_options:
    defaults:
      remote_user: molecule
```

Comment: That's the default user. Did you try try adding a new user and test with that?

Comment: @Azeem sorry, but it is not clear to me what you are suggesting. I believe you are saying `runner` is the default user for Github Actions. I added the user `molecule` to the image, but when I run it uses the `runner` user. I need to find a way to replace this GA user.

Comment: Yes, I was pointing out that the `runner` is the default user. I was suggesting that you might be able to add a new user, switch to that, and then test. Also, please include your relevant workflow in your question. I'm not well-versed with ansible but I believe it's similar to chef. If you could add more context that'd be helpful to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem do you know an option on GA to change this default user that run the command?

Comment: AFAIK, you may add new user, switch to it, and the next commands should under that user. You can try this. However, binding to a specific user doesn't sound good.

Comment: I add the user already in the test docker images I use. So I want to execute provisioning already with this user.

Comment: Right. If you could share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a public repo, that'd be very helpful to understand and debug this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254526/discussion-between-staticdev-and-azeem).

Comment: see https://github.com/Ableton/ansible-role-nix/blob/main/defaults/main.yml#L9

https://github.com/staticdev/nix-playbook/actions/runs/5595438272/jobs/10231306398#step:7:876

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables

https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/molecule/examples/#docker-with-non-privileged-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the provisioner user (`molecule`) path was not the default path for the ansible role that I was using but a fallback path. In my test machine I do not have a `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` set, so it works. But GitHub Actions sets it to use `runner` user path to do the configs instead of the user I create for molecule images.

The way to bypass it is by forcing GitHub Actions to clean the value of `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` when running molecule, then everything works:

```yaml
    - name: Run Molecule tests
      run: molecule test
      env:
        PY_COLORS: "1"
        ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR: "1"
        MOLECULE_DISTRO: ${{ matrix.distro }}
        XDG_CONFIG_HOME: ""
```